# Non-recursive method for finding \$a^n\$

Tags: java, recursion, interview-questions, complexity

I am working on an interview question from [Amazon Software](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Amazon-com-Software-Development-Engineer-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE6036.0,10_KO11,47_IP7.htm). The particular question I am working on is "to write a program to find \$a^n\$."

Here is my recursive solution to this problem (in Java):

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
     if(n == 0) {
          return 1;
     } else {
          return a * pow(a, n -1 );
     }         
}
```

I did some runtime analysis and found that this solution runs in \$O(n)\$ time - recurrence relation with \$T(n) = 3 + T(n-1)\$, \$T(0)=1\$, and \$O(n)\$ space - depth of memory stack is \$n\$, with two local variables at each call, \$2n\$ total.

We are always taught to optimize our code in terms of space complexity and time complexity, so here is another solution that I came up with:

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
     int result = 1;
     for(int count=0;count<n;count++) {
           result *= a;
     }
     return result;
}
```

Would this solution be more efficient than the first one? This one runs in \$O(n)\$ time-loop until \$n\$ and \$O(1)\$ space - four units of space - one for `a`, `n`, `result`, and `count`.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've partially rolled back your Rev 2 changes.

Comment: Remember, $a$ can be a double or even a complex number or a matrix. It's just $n$ that has to be an integer. And... just use an unsigned int. Negative arguments aren't valid for this algorithm.

Comment: no unsigned integer in java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java. My solution would be to have checker and an illegal argument exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a more efficient method using squaring:

```
int result = 1;
while(n>0){
    if(n%2 == 1)result*=a;
    a *= a;
    n /= 2;
}
```

Or in recursive notation:

```
int pow(int base, int exponent) {
     if(exponent == 0) {
          return 1;
     } else if(exponent%2 == 1){
          return base * pow(base*base, exponent / 2 );
     } else {
          return pow(base*base, exponent / 2 );
     }
}
```

This works because

\$\$ a^n = \begin{cases}
(a^2)^{\frac{n}{2}} & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
a \cdot (a^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}\$\$

Comment: What value is result initially set to in the first solution?

Comment: Can you optimize this further, in the same pattern, using the fact that \$a^n = (a^3)^(n/3)\$ now the function being in O(\$log_3n)\$?

Comment: What would space complexity be in the recursive solution?

Comment: Space complexity in a recursive solution is proportional to the number of iterations because the recursive call frames are kept on the stack - $O(\log_2 n)$ for the squaring solution. And no, using a different base would make it worse. First of all, you live in a binary world so you are just looking which bytes are 1 (there is effectively no division and remainder operation - just bit shift and looking at the first bit). Secondly, this method achieves the optimal number of multiplications - bisection (which this is) gets there the fastest - dividing into more sections is always worse.

Comment: `result` must be initialized to `1`.

Comment: @orion to me if you have a different base, say 3, you have n/= 3 inside while loop making n reach 0 sooner.

Comment: @committedandroider but it doesn't really matter in the long run, because the relation between `log_2 n` and `log_3 n` is `log 3 / log 2` and you lose the gain with the extra multiplies

Comment: @committedandroider
The loop has less iterations, but only by a constant factor, so the big-O complexity is the same. Additionally, every iteraton must then perform more multiplications, so at the end it's slower. For the better known root finding algorithms, the bisection requires $\ln \epsilon/\ln 2$ function calls, while trisection is $1.66\ln \epsilon /\ln 3$ and quadrisection $2.25 \ln \epsilon/\ln 4$, which is getting progressively worse. $\epsilon$ is the ratio between the desired accuracy and the initial interval. Here it's similar. You can almost always assume base-2 is the best.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: if you squeeze more linear complexity work into one iteration, you are slowly getting back from O(log n) to O(n): you are losing the advantage of divide-and-conquer strategy.

Comment: Can you explain "but only by a constant factor", Isn't \$log_2\$ different from \$log_3\$?

Comment: @committedandroider but `log_3 n = (log_2 n) / (log_2 3)`

Comment: I've downvoted because this is just an alternative, not a review. It is a good recommendation though, if you expand the answer to an actual review and direct a comment at me I'll change it to an upvote.

Comment: @BenAaronson I don't think this deserves a downvote. He reviewed me a code and gave me a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

- `n` is `int`, which means it could be negative. The recursive version would run forever, and an iterative version would produce a wrong result.
- Complexity analysis of your algorithms is correct, however...
- ... I don't want to spoil your pleasure of finding a \$O(\log{n})\$ solution - just keep in mind that it is possible.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I should guard against that with an IllegalArgumentException